# Create or smart merge with MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

Let's assume that this is my document:

```
public class ElcoRequest
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public int Result { get; set; }

    public List<string> Equations { get; set; }

}
```

The users are sending me many equations. I'm solving the equation and save the result and the source equation into a document within MongoDB.

Now, many equation can be with same result.

Before creating new document in db, I want to check for first that the same result is not exists. If requested result exists, just modify the existing result with new equation. Something like this:

```
doc.Equations.add(newOne);
```

Please give attention to the fact that whole process is multi-threaded. So, each document can be modified\deleted\inserted from more then one thread. On relative databases, it's remind me transaction.

Looking for implementation advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a document update, that queries for the existing document and adds the equations if it finds it. If it doesn't it inserts a new document instead. You do that using the `UpdateFlags.Upsert` flag:

```
collection.Update(
    Query.And(Query<ElcoRequest>.EQ(r => r.Id, newRequest.Id),
        Query<ElcoRequest>.EQ(r => r.Result, newRequest.Result)),
    Update<ElcoRequest>.PushAll(r => r.Equations, newRequest.Equations),
    UpdateFlags.Upsert);
```

Comment: Is this thread-safe? what if I'm running this code from several programs (aka process-safe)?

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Yes, mongo has a database level lock.